# Что с регистром у действий под сообщением?

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, дизайн

Почему 3 кнопки с маленькой буквы, а 5 с большой?

> поделиться
> Править
> откат
> Отслеживать
> Закрыть
> Удалить
> тревога
> Мод

[image: скриншот 1]

[image: скриншот 2]

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359477/capitalization-of-post-action-links-is-causing-multiple-rows-of-links

Comment: Ад перфекциониста

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, на тех скринах всё с заглавных.

Comment: @Qwertiy О, правда... Значит моя правка неправильная...

Comment: В переводах все ОК. "Share" переведено как "Поделиться" с большой буквы. Скорее всего, еще не все изменения строк дошли до локализованных сайтов.

Comment: Регистр стал одинаковый, но всё равно верните как было

Comment: @andreymal, `.js-post-menu a, .js-post-menu button { text-transform: lowercase; }`

Comment: Отслеживать после нажатия становится Following

Comment: @Jack_oS, думаю, это совершенно отдельный баг.